# toLocaleTimeString() returning military time

Tags: javascript, date

I have a function that converts a SQL datetime stamp into a formatted time.  It looks good on an iOS device, but its displayed as military time on an android device.  How can I get this to return the toLocaleTimeString() as not military time on an android device?

```
function fromDateString(str) {
    var res = str.match(/\/Date\((\d+)(?:([+-])(\d\d)(\d\d))?\)\//);
    if (res == null)
        return new Date(NaN); // or something that indicates it was not a DateString
    var time = parseInt(res[1], 10);
    if (res[2] && res[3] && res[4]) {
        var dir = res[2] == "+" ? -1 : 1,
            h = parseInt(res[3], 10),
            m = parseInt(res[4], 10);
        time += dir * (h*60+m) * 60000;
    }
    return formatdate.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the android device is set to use a 24 hour clock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()` function`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.7) is "implementation dependent" which means that if you want to guarantee a certain format on all devices then you must apply it yourself.

Here's how I would do it:

```javascript
function formatTimeString(date) {
  if ((typeof(date)!=='object') || (date.constructor!==Date)) {
    throw new Error('argument must be a Date object');
  }
  function pad(s) { return ((''+s).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + s; }
  function fixHour(h) { return (h==0?'12':(h>12?h-12:h)); }
  var h=date.getHours(), m=date.getMinutes(), s=date.getSeconds()
    , timeStr=[pad(fixHour(h)), pad(m), pad(s)].join(':');
  return timeStr + ' ' + (h < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
}

formatTimeString(new Date());
// => "09:19:03 AM"
formatTimeString(new Date('2012-12-19T20:09:10-0700'));
// => "08:09:10 PM"
formatTimeString(new Date('2012-12-19T00:13:14-0700'));
// => "12:13:14 AM"
```

Comment: how would i do that? i am trying to break it down to hours and minutes,  but the Date Object does not work with the length function and the length function does not work with the Date Object